# random color based on cell value(Name column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to have the formula or Macro which can give me below output.

If you see below example. I need color row based on Name column.

For example: Name A has 2 records both rows should be highlighted with the same color.
I can do this with conditional formatting, but I have too many values in *name* column and this is the main reason I'm looking for macro.

```
INC-No  Host    Name
INC1    x1      e1
INC2    x2      e2
INC3    x3      e3
INC4    x4      e2
INC5    x5      e5
INC6    x6      e1
INC7    x7      e3
```

Thanks
Harsha

Comment: @teylyn Sorry... You can parse the character into an integer with `COLUMN(INDIRECT(C2&1))` which could be colour scaled though this would need a helper column that can be hidden... Only assuming that the name is actually a character representing a column ofcourse.

Comment: @RichardTompsett That'll only work if the names are indeed up to 3 characters long and up to XFD, since you need a valid column reference. - Edit: Nevermind, just saw your edit.

Comment: @Olly - I have 30-40 unique names in the Name column. I can use conditional formatting option, But because of the below reason iam looking for macro. 
1 - 30-40 unique names as of now
2 - New employee joins i need add one more entry 
3 - I require this to publish report to users

Comment: nothing in your question makes sense. i think you should first read about what conditional formatting actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `name` is in Column C and the data is on the `Sheet1` object (change references as needed):

```
Sub Test()
Dim nameCount As Integer
Dim names() As String
Dim i As Integer

nameCount = -1
ReDim Preserve names(0 To 0)
For i = 2 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If UBound(Filter(names, Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value)) = -1 Then
        nameCount = nameCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve names(0 To nameCount)
        names(nameCount) = Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value
    End If
    Sheet1.Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Interior.colorIndex = Application.Match(Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value, names, False)
Next i
End Sub
```

The above builds an array and adds an element each time a name is encountered that isn't in the array yet. It uses the array index of the unique name as colorIndex.

Since it uses colorIndex, the maximum number of unique names is 57.
If you have more, you should use RGB values or something else.

Code is tested, but not optimized in any way and has no error handling whatsoever. Given the attempts made in the "question", this is enough to get you started. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the Macro. Quick Q , Its taking same color one with more brightness and one with dim color.

Comment: It's using colorIndex, what can I say. http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm
N.b. if it does what you need, consider marking your question as answered. If you have a follow-up about how to set what specific color you actually want, post a new question. - You asked for unique and this is it.